# href is not sending good link information

Tags: django, python-3.x

My code create a link that is like that:/peoplebook/users/list/%7B%%20url%20'people-users-detail'%20key
which create an error

don t know what to try differently

my code in urls.pyfrom django.urls import path

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', views.users_list),
    path('users/<str:display>/', views.users_list),
    path('users/<str:name>/detail/', views.users_detail, name='peoplebook-users-detail'),

]
```

and in my html file

```
{% block content %}
    <h2> Test Titre</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for key, user in users.items %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'peoplebook-users-detail' key %}">{{ user.name|title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock content %}}
```

should be like url :

http.../peoplebook/userrs/han/detail

han is users.name

Answer (score -2):

in ur models u have to add one more attribute to ur MODEL which is a SlugField
take a look at this documentation link:--
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/

plz upload ur models.py file if u cant find solution in the documentation